# Unable to subclass with Builder pattern: Shipment(Builder) is not public in Shipment; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, package, subclass, builder, extends

I have the code below, where I am trying to extend a class, but the constructor has the following error:

"Shipment(Builder) is not public in Shipment; cannot be accessed from outside package."

None of the other answers on SO seem to apply or fix the problem. I'm grateful for any direction...

My subclass:

```
public class ShipmentSubclass extends Shipment {

public double foo; 

public ShipmentSubclass(Builder builder) {
  super(builder);
  this.foo = 0.0;
}
```

And Shipment is defined in another package (imported as a jar):

```
public class Shipment{

  public static class Builder {
    private String id;
    public Builder(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Shipment build() {
        return new Shipment(this);
    }
  }

  private final String id;

  public Shipment(Builder builder) {
    this.id = builder.id;
  }
}
```

Comment: I pasted your code locally and it works just fine for me. Also the Shipment(Builder) function is clearly public in Shipment class, so i'm wondering if you are using the same code as you pasted?

Comment: The true code is more complicated. The parent class Shipment is from another package, which I've added as a Jar. I did the same in a new project, and the error only occurs when trying to extend the parent from the other package. I edited the question to note this.

Comment: Ok, but then the error message is probably correct. In your "real" code, the constructor Shipment(Builder builder) is private and Shipment is from another package. So you either need to move to same package, or make that constructor public, if you can.

Comment: I had found that suggestion here on SO, but unfortunately the constructor Shipment(Builder builder) is public already (I have the source too). I don't want to move to the same package if I can avoid it, as I don't want to mix the 3rd party library in with my code base.

Comment: The code you have provided compiles without the aforementioned error. You should post the smallest sample of code which actually demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours on this, I gave up [on Netbeans] and made a new project in Eclipse Neon. The same issue persisted with subclassing a class from a jar, but I added the source as a required project, the error went away, and I proceeded.